# How to center image in Span

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to center image in `<span>` tag?

[image]

```
<div class="col-1">
     <span class="dot">
           <h:graphicImage library="imgs" name="campus.png" width="25" height="25" style="align-content-center"/>
     </span>
</div>
```

**dot** css

```
.dot {
     height: 75px;
     width: 75px;
     background-color: #bbb;
     border-radius: 50%;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Don't worry about `h:graphicImage`, it is a **JSF** tag which translates to `<img>` in html. Any html class can be applied to it.

I am using [Bootstrap 4.3](https://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: did you tried using either text-align:center OR margin:0 auto ?

Comment: Applying `text-align:center` to `<h:graphicImage>` only aligns image to center horizontally.

Comment: couple up with vertical-align:middle

Answer (score 0):

```
.dot {
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
}

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="dot" src="campus.png"/></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is this **span4**?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try Display Flex and align items and justify content to center.

```
.dot {
 height: 75px;
 width: 75px;
 background-color: #bbb;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave this a try, I couldn’t comment so I had to code this. I used `position: absolute`. Hope this helps!

```css
.dot {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: #bbb;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.campus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11.5%;
  left: 8%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="col-1">
     <span class="dot">
           <img src="https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/campus-png-5.png" width="25" height="25" style="align-content-center" class="campus"/>
     </span>
</div>
```